# How to connect button to adaptive background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, layout

Just started learning web layout. And I ran into such a problem: there is a picture on the background (these frames, you don’t need to suggest using border in CSS since this is just a test background!)
this picture changes due to screen expansion, with this code:

```css
body {
    background-image: url('imgs/test_bg.png');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #464646;
}
```

```html
<div class="register-form">
  <label>
    <input class="asda" name="login" />
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="asda" name="login" />
  </label>
</div>
```

but I don’t know how to attach an input to this image, and a button that will be like an image so that the input is always in the frame

##### Example: 1920x1080

[image: 1920x1080]

##### Example: 1351x961

[image: 1351x961]

##### [video demo](https://youtu.be/0AYJn2xJdDE) *(YouTube Link)*

I searched for an answer to my question, but nothing helped

Comment: Can you also post the HTML code?  It's hard know how to fix the problem with only the CSS from your code.

Comment: @FiniteLooper, could not properly adjust the formatting of the code in the comment, added it to the description of the issue

Comment: I've converted the code you posted into a snippet which can be run here inside your question.  It doesn't seem to look anything like your screenshots or video.  There is still some code missing. Until that is in your question it's extremely difficult to give you an answer for what might be wrong.  You need to a post a completely reproducible example in your question to make it easy for someone to answer without guessing at what you might mean or what the issue could be.